# WP массовые изменения acf полей

Tags: wordpress, acf

использую acf плагин для мета полей в кастомных записях, все отлично работает, по повилась задача сделать отдельную страницу где будут все кастомные записи с возможность выбрать нужные и заменить в них например улицу, номер дома и т. д.

Подскажите пожалуйста какое-то решение или ссылку на похожий код, искал целы день, ничего найти не могу.

Спасибо.

Comment: Есть плагин с нужным функционалом WEPB bulk editr, но он слишком нагружен и  не очень удобен в использовании, хочу сделать страницу только с фильтром и массовым редактором полей в  выбранных записях

Answer (score 0):

Все данные acf хранятся в таблицах #__posts, #__postmeta

Для полей создается custom post type "acf-field"

Также в #__postmeta сохраняются данные вида

```
'field_name', 'field_value',
'_field_name', 'field_key'
```

Попробуйте реализовать массовое изменение непосредственно через класс доступа к базе $wpdb